# Convert Hex string value to Hex number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, hexadecimal

Say A1 contains the string "f26e". It's a hex value that I want to use in the Unichar function, but since it's a string, I would need to convert it as a number (UNICHAR(A1) returns an error in value). VALUE() doesn't work. I guess it can only take decimal values.

Thanks!

R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`HEX2DEC`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HEX2DEC-function-8c8c3155-9f37-45a5-a3ee-ee5379ef106e) function to convert hexadecimal numbers to decimal ones.

Comment: Duh! I didn't think it would take a string as input! Thanks!

Comment: Excel knows only decimal numbers, it can store (and recognize) hexadecimal numbers only as string.